# Как устроить связь кодировок рабочего времени в базе данных? я делаю табель учета рабочего времени, ниже я привел сущности и пример кодировки

Tags: postgresql

Сущности:

> • Департаменты;
>
> • Сотрудники;
>
> • Производственный календарь – календарь рабочих, выходных, предпраздничных и праздничных дней на год;
>
> • Виды отметок с кодировкой на работе, с кодировкой:
>
> > Я – полный рабочий день;
> >
> > Н – отсутствие на рабочее место по невыясненным причинам;
> >
> > В – выходные и праздничные дни;
> >
> > Рв – работа в праздничные и выходные дни; а также работа в праздничные и выходные дни, при нахождении в командировке;
> >
> > Б – дни временной нетрудоспособности;

Как это можно реализовать? интересует именно связь между таблицами.

Answer (score 1):

Твоя прога будет показывать посещаемость сотрудников. Так что основное отношение в твоей РБД это

Дата - ключ сотрудника - кодировка посещаемости.

Прога будет делать запрос типа.

```
SELECT кодировка
FROM таблица_посещаемости 
WHERE колонка_дат = нужный нам день AND колонка_номера_сотрудника = ключ сотрудника
```

Дальше ветвись референсами в разные стороны и не забывай о 3NF, дроби как можно чаще, запросы потом будешь делать через JOIN и трехэтажные (или создавать VIEW если нужно, но так покажешь работодателю, что шаришь в нормализации и умеешь избегать аномалий.  Календарь как сущность тут  непонятно зачем нужен, наверное проверять соответствия кодировок с реальными выходными/рабочими днями. Но его реализовать совсем просто ( Дата - тип дня ) дата тут будет первичным ключом, а в таблице_посещаемости внешним. Тут все просто. Удачи.